# Generate random image over a button

Tags: ios, swift, image, random, arc4random

I'm working on a project to generate random images from an array. I'm running into an issue. I will have one button on the screen name `generage shapes`. Once the user clicks on this button the `generate shapes` button becomes hidden and 4 buttons display 4 different shapes. I'm having an issue making these 4 buttons display with the image from my array. I tried a switch statement but it doesn't go through. I'm providing my code below.

```
import UIKit

class ShapesDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var random = arc4random_uniform(4)

    @IBOutlet weak var titleBar: UINavigationItem!

    @IBOutlet weak var displayMessageLabel: UILabel!

    var myImages = [ "diamond.png", "decagon.png", "dodecagon.png", "hectagon.png", "heptagon.png", "octagon.png", "parallelogram.png", "pentagon.png", "rectangle.png", "rightTriangle.png", "square.png", "trapezoid.png", "triangle.png"]

    //my image labels

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonThree: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonFour: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var generateImage: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.buttonFour.hidden = true
        self.buttonOne.hidden = true
        self.buttonThree.hidden = true
        self.buttonTwo.hidden = true
        displayMessageLabel.hidden = true

    }

    @IBAction func generateRandomImages(sender: AnyObject) {

        displayMessageLabel.hidden = false

        buttonOne.hidden = false

        switch(random){

        case 0: buttonOne.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "circle.png")
            break

        case 1: buttonOne.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "decagon.png")
            break

        case 2: buttonOne.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "diamond.png")
            break

        case 3: buttonOne.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "hectagon.png")
            break
        default:
            break;

        }

        generateImage.hidden = true
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you can't change a button's image by its image view property, you need to use the setter method for the image. Something like this:

```
buttonOne.setImage(UIImage(named: "circle"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: should this be a switch statement to make this happen?